# How do I get base address from memory when an Android app (APK) is run?

Tags: android, apk, frida

I am using frida for studying android app and reverse engineering. 
I want to scan memory for any sensitive data being leaked or not. 
From frida's API, I can scan the memory using `Memory.Scan` function but the problem here is the arguments. `Memory.Scan` accepts `address` as first argument but I am not sure which address to input. Another API call to `Process.enumerateRangesSync()` gives me base address of all the loaded modules by this app but I am confused with base address.

Any pointers will highly help me in clearing this doubt.

TIA

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. You are talking about the internal storage? Do you want to check device storage data?

Comment: @FaridHaq I am talking about runtime.  heap memory.

Comment: Process memory is not one block, but partitioned, therefore you have to scan each block individually. Here is an example that basically shows how to scan: https://github.com/poxyran/misc/blob/master/frida-memory-scan.py

Comment: @Robert : Thank you for the reference link. I am having a look.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.enumerateModulesSync()` will yield something like

```
   [
    {
        "base": "0x7eb50e1000",
        "name": "linux-vdso.so.1",
        "path": "linux-vdso.so.1",
        "size": 4096
    },
    {
        "base": "0x7eb50e2000",
        "name": "linker64",
        "path": "/system/bin/linker64",
        "size": 1003520
    }
]
```

the `base` is the base address of corresponding module,

normally you are seeking module named `base.odex`

the term `base address` is firmly tied with `ASLR`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 0):

You can use via LeakCanary Third party open source library for scan class file  memory leaked or not in your app.

https://square.github.io/leakcanary/